# How to select from list options within loop through them select each option and find the value from database - using selenium webdriver - JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I want it to be in for **loop**, that to **find the date from dropdown and match it with the date which is stored in database**. and then select it.otherwise test case Failed.

for mean while. I'm beginners in selenium. so I just want to add on my work place a new things.
the dropdown name is " Year of Birth ", that having multiple years.

I will appreciate that. thanks

Note: **able to select from Option for each value**. but **my question** here to add a loop condition that to match the data from the database.

Comment: Is it possible to share the link and piece of code that you have tried.

Comment: why do you need a loop ? How are you reading data from DB ?

Comment: @cruisepandey using loop its faster to pick the date which is stored in DB. I want it to search that date with is same. I've used Fillo API which is stored the data in Excel sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED BY USING

```
driver.findElement(YearOfBisrth).click();
        Select selectBirth = new Select(driver.findElement(YearOfBisrth));
        driver.findElement(YearOfBisrth).click();
        selectBirth.selectByValue(data.get("YearBirth"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example:

```
package selenium;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Malikah extends WebDriverSetup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver(); // standard chromedriver init
        driver.get("https://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/select-dropdown-menu/");
        WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.tagName("select"));
        Select select = new Select(dropDown);
        List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();
        for (WebElement option: options) {
            select.selectByValue(option.getAttribute("value"));
            System.out.println("Selected option's text: " + select.getFirstSelectedOption().getText());
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 91.0.4472.101 (af52a90bf87030dd1523486a1cd3ae25c5d76c9b-refs/branch-heads/4472@{#1462}) on port 39875
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1627992309.880][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 92.
Srp 03, 2021 2:05:09 ODP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Selected option's text: Afghanistan
Selected option's text: ?land Islands
Selected option's text: Albania
Selected option's text: Algeria
Selected option's text: American Samoa
Selected option's text: Andorra
Selected option's text: Angola
...
```

Comment: Thanks i will  post my Answer. @pburgr